# How to call .Net Post Api with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, asp.net-core, json.net

I've a .net endpoint which returns a jwt token like below
[image]

I tried to call this endpoint from JavaScript

```
  const response = await fetch("http://users:6400/api/authenticate/get_token", {
        method: 'POST',
        mode: 'cors',
        cache: 'no-cache',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            username: username,
            password: password,
            application_id:'44c5b142-6b05-4d29-98b3-5501ef71db0f',
            web_site:'WakeNC'
        })
    }).then((response) => {             
        if(response.ok) 
        {
            const myJson =  response.json();
             return response.json();               
        }
    }).catch((error) => {             
        console.log(error);
    });
```

here i'm getting success response, but I'm not able to read the token value
i've added the received response value below
[image]

let me know if anything I've to change, thanks

Comment: Hows your controller code? can include that one as well?

Comment: [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost("get_token")]
        public ActionResult<TokenResponseModel> Authenticate([FromBody] AuthenticateModel authenticateModel)
        {
         }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Response.json()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/json) method returns a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). So, you need to await it to get data:

```js
const response = await fetch("http://users:6400/api/authenticate/get_token", {
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'cors',
    cache: 'no-cache',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        username: username,
        password: password,
        application_id:'44c5b142-6b05-4d29-98b3-5501ef71db0f',
        web_site:'WakeNC'
    })
}).then(async (response) => {             
    if (response.ok) 
    {
        let myJson = await response.json();
        console.log(myJson);              
    }
}).catch((error) => {             
    console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: In my test with json doesn't work as response.json();. Because API response already in json result so we no longer need to read from json. I have shared details trace and debug result.

Answer (score 1):

> here i'm getting success response, but I'm not able to read the token
> value i've added the received response value below

I found the issue in your `response.json();` which doesn't contains the token because its not asynchronous and execution got faild. Instead you should read token from  `const result = await response.text();`. Another important point is if you have response viewModel you would read response from model proprty as following:

```
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Authenticate([FromBody] LoginViewModel loginInfo)
        {
            IActionResult response = Unauthorized();

            var user = await _authenticationService.AuthenticateLogin(loginInfo);

            if (user.Token != null)
            {
                response = Ok(new ResponseViewModel { output = "success", msg = "Login Successfully", apiResponse = user });
            }

            return response;
        }
```

[image]

But if your API just returns token you can direct get that token in response as following:

```
response = Ok(user.Token);
```

[image]

Let's have a look on practice:

```
const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5094/api/Authenticate", {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },

                body: JSON.stringify({
                    username: username,
                    password: password,
                    application_id:'44c5b142-6b05-4d29-98b3-5501ef71db0f',
                    web_site:'WakeNC'
                   
                })
            });
            console.log("Rquest Submitted");
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error(response.statusText);
            }

            const result = await response.text();
```

Output:

[image]

**Note:** Take ways from my investigation, please try with await response.text();